# How to handle many-to-many relationships with multiple incompatible relationship types in RESTful API?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, relationships

> Note this question is about when there are multiple relationship types. This is not the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api), where there is only a single `member` relationship.

Say we have `persons` and `organizations`. There are two types of relationships between them. One is `employment` and the other is `customer`.

I'd like to be able to get the `persons` associated with an `organization` based on either `employment` or `customer`, as well as the inverse, getting the `organizations` associated with a `person` based on either `employment` or `customer`.

Usually when I have relationships like this id just go with:

```
/persons/<person_id>/organization
/organizations/<organization_id>/person
```

Now, how should I represent this when the type of relationship is ambiguous, in my example it could be either `employment` or `customer`. Here are some alternatives I've come up with for accessing all `persons` who are `customers` of an `organization`:

```
/customers/organizations/<organization_id>/persons
/organizations/<organization_id>/customers/persons
/organizations/<organization_id>/persons?only_customers=true
/organizations/<organization_id>/persons?relationship=customer
```

Under the hood these would be modeled as four DB tables:

```
person <- customer -> organization
person <- employment -> organization
```

Are there any other ways of doing this? Which would be the canonical way? I'm not very keen on creating new object types. It might be obvious that `person` could be replaced with `employee`, or something like that, but that would have huge implications for other parts of the API design and client implementation, thus is not on the table.

Comment: Return a generic entity, perhaps a "contact."

Comment: Looks like employment and customer are mere query strings of /organization and /person. No need to be represented as a hiearchy.

Answer (score 0):

Reminder: REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI.

As far as REST is concerned, it is perfectly reasonable for `ACME Inc` to be identified by `/a05b7d44-8319-4609-bb17-6234b0a61e54`, and for `ACME Inc Employees` to be identified by `/2ae6f0a9-e8ea-4b0d-899e-39a11cd92fe1` and for `ACME Inc Customers` to be identified by `/fcb01a22-8dd6-45d6-a489-da143fca834e`.

At the server, you might prefer to instead use a hierarchical spelling, because doing so would allow you to take advantage of [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2).  So you might instead have
`/a05b7d44-8319-4609-bb17-6234b0a61e54`, `/a05b7d44-8319-4609-bb17-6234b0a61e54/2ae6f0a9-e8ea-4b0d-899e-39a11cd92fe1`, `/a05b7d44-8319-4609-bb17-6234b0a61e54/fcb01a22-8dd6-45d6-a489-da143fca834e`, allowing you to use dot-segments to move up the identifier hierarchy.

You would normally rely on [links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2) to communicate the relation between two URI.

What this does is allows the server to encode into the URI any information it needs to resolve the correct resource later.  That allows us to use spellings like

```
/organization/7/employees
/employees/organization/7
/employees?organization=7
/organization/7?employees
/orgnization/7/people?employees
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the top level resource name matching the objects you are returning

```
/person/GetByCustomerOfOrgId?OrgId=xxxx
/person/GetByEmployerOrgId?OrgId=xxxx
/organisation/GetByCustomerPersonId?PersonId=xxxx
```

You'll have to excuse my RPC style naming, I feel its simply the most obvious way to express the relationship in a simple string.

However, the principle is that you are returning a Person or list of Person then use the Person resource.

Don't do

```
/organisation/{id}/customers  <-- returns List<Person>
/person/{id}/employer   <-- returns organisation
```

Although it might look neat for simple examples, you'll end up looping over all the people in the world when you want to do something more complicated like people who have been employed by an organisation who I am a customer of, instead of just added a new method